# JavaScript ReferenceError - object is not defined when running npm test

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

Sorry if the answer to this is really obvious but I cannot work out what is wrong.

I have made a simple bill splitting app which all works fine. I am trying to write tests and am using Jasmine.

My code is as follows:

```
    function Bill_Splitter(){

      this.amount = 0;

    };
```

And my spec is:

```
   describe('Bill_Splitter', function() {
     var splitter;

     beforeEach(function() {
       splitter = new Bill_Splitter();
     });

     describe('splitter', function() {
       it('has a default amount of 0', function(){
         expect(splitter.amount).toEqual(0);
       });
     });
   });
```

When I run `npm test` in my terminal, the error is as follows:

```
ReferenceError: Bill_Splitter is not defined
```

Can anyone please help with why this is? I am relatively new to JavaScript!

Thanks :)

Update:

File directory:

```
.
├── README.md
├── girl-and-money.png
├── index.html
├── node_modules
│   ├── balanced-match
│   │   ├── LICENSE.md
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── brace-expansion
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── concat-map
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.markdown
│   │   ├── example
│   │   │   └── map.js
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── map.js
│   ├── fs.realpath
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── old.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── glob
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── changelog.md
│   │   ├── common.js
│   │   ├── glob.js
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── sync.js
│   ├── inflight
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── inflight.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── inherits
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── inherits.js
│   │   ├── inherits_browser.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── jasmine
│   │   ├── Gruntfile.js
│   │   ├── MIT.LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   │   └── jasmine.js
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── command.js
│   │   │   ├── examples
│   │   │   │   └── jasmine.json
│   │   │   ├── filters
│   │   │   │   └── console_spec_filter.js
│   │   │   ├── jasmine.js
│   │   │   └── reporters
│   │   │       ├── completion_reporter.js
│   │   │       └── console_reporter.js
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── jasmine.js
│   ├── jasmine-core
│   │   ├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
│   │   ├── MANIFEST.in
│   │   ├── MIT.LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── RELEASE.md
│   │   ├── bower.json
│   │   ├── ci.js
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── jasmine-horizontal.png
│   │   │   ├── jasmine-horizontal.svg
│   │   │   └── jasmine_favicon.png
│   │   ├── jasmine_core.egg-info
│   │   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   │   ├── requires.txt
│   │   │   └── top_level.txt
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── jasmine-core
│   │   │   │   ├── boot.js
│   │   │   │   ├── example
│   │   │   │   │   ├── node_example
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── jasmine_examples
│   │   │   │   │   │   │       ├── Player.js
│   │   │   │   │   │   │       └── Song.js
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── spec
│   │   │   │   │   │       ├── helpers
│   │   │   │   │   │       │   └── jasmine_examples
│   │   │   │   │   │       │       └── SpecHelper.js
│   │   │   │   │   │       └── jasmine_examples
│   │   │   │   │   │           └── PlayerSpec.js
│   │   │   │   │   ├── spec
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── PlayerSpec.js
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── SpecHelper.js
│   │   │   │   │   └── src
│   │   │   │   │       ├── Player.js
│   │   │   │   │       └── Song.js
│   │   │   │   ├── jasmine-html.js
│   │   │   │   ├── jasmine.css
│   │   │   │   ├── jasmine.js
│   │   │   │   ├── json2.js
│   │   │   │   └── node_boot.js
│   │   │   └── jasmine-core.js
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── requirements.txt
│   ├── minimatch
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── minimatch.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── once
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── once.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── path-is-absolute
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── license
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── readme.md
│   ├── spec
│   │   ├── billSplitterSpec.js
│   │   └── support
│   │       └── jasmine.json
│   ├── src
│   │   └── billSplitter.js
│   └── wrappy
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── package.json
│       └── wrappy.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── skeleton.css
```

Comment: Are these two part of code in the same file?

Comment: No - top is in billSplitter.js in a Src file and the second is billSplitterSpec.js in a Spec file

Comment: You need to require it in the test file then `const Bill_Splitter = require('./Bill_splitter')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `require` those files you want to use in your tests in this way:

```
// Bill_Splitter.js
module.exports = function(){
    this.amount = 0;
};
```

```
// billSplitterSpec.js
const Bill_Splitter = require('../src/billSplitter')

describe('Bill_Splitter', function() {
    var splitter;

    beforeEach(function() {
        splitter = new Bill_Splitter();
    });

    describe('splitter', function() {
        it('has a default amount of 0', function(){
            expect(splitter.amount).toEqual(0);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I am now receiving the error: `Cannot find module './billSplitter'` (billSplitter is the name of the file)

Comment: are these two files in the same directory? `billSplitter` and your `specs` file.

Comment: no billSplitter is in a src file and billSplitterSpec is in a spec file. Both files are in the same directory

Comment: could you share your directory structure in a picture or ...? Before that try this one: `const Bill_Splitter = require('../src/billSplitter')`

Comment: It's weird! `const Bill_Splitter = require('../src/billSplitter')` should solve the problem but I really don't know why it does not. As a note, all your files reside on `node_modules` which should not be so!

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway ! :) Ah yes - this happened automatically when I ran npm install jasmine. Should all of them be extracted or just the spec and src files?

Comment: You're welcome. All of your files should be put out of `node_modules` directory in order to make it maintainable and have more control over your code. All packages within `node_modules` can be install using a `npm install` command and your codes should not be among them because when we deploy project, it's server task to install those packages.